# Does javascript require reference to object when using its props/methods?

Tags: javascript, object

When I retrieve info through either of the following versions, I get correct results:

```
window.screen.height
```

VS:

```
screen.height
```

Is it required/advised to write the 'window.' portion, or can I leave it out?

Does this also apply to accessing document.properties/methods and other objects - I never need to write the 'document.' portion (or whatever object I am accessing from)?

Comment: This reminds me of the time I named one of my variables 'location'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it required/adviced to write the 'window.' portion or can I leave it out?

This specific example (a property on `window`, in browsers) is a special case; no, you don't have to write `window`. In *general*, you do have to specify the object reference.

It's a special case because `screen` is a property of the global object, which makes it a global variable. `window` is *also* a property of the global object, which is a reference to...the global object. So `window.screen` and `screen` refer to the same thing, the property called "screen" on the global object. You could also write `window.window.screen` or `window.window.window.screen` and so on. :-) A bit of ASCII-art may be useful:

```
        /-----------------\
        |                 |
        v                 |
+-------------------+     |
| The Global Object |     |
+-------------------+     |
| window            |----/            +-------------------+
| screen            |---------------->| The Screen Object |
| (other globals).. |                 +-------------------+
+-------------------+
```

As you can see, the `window` property on the global object refers back to the global object.

But again, it's a special case.

---

Side point: JavaScript does make it possible for you to use an implicit object reference when not dealing with the global object, using the `with` statement

```
var obj = {foo: "bar"};
with (obj) {
    console.log(foo); // "bar"
}
```

...but that can be very confusing, so using `with` is widely discouraged (and in fact, disallowed in the new(ish) "strict" mode of the language).

Answer (score 3):

Global variables are mirrored in the window object as properties. Many document properties are also on window but those that aren't, cannot be referenced without writing `document.`